# Modelling a rocket

Tags: mesh

I'm making a scene of a German V2 rocket being launched, and I'm stuck on the body.  What is the best way to do it?  It has to be quite high poly so that the surface looks smooth, or I would just use Scale on a cylinder.

Comment: I'd start with a circle with plenty of vertices, and extrude upwards and scale each extrusion to get the slight bulge.

Comment: Welcome to the site moran!  I would suggest watching some tutorial videos on sites like [Blender Cookie](http://cgcookie.com/blender) or [Blenderguru.com](http://www.Blenderguru.com).  Jonathan Williamson's [Intro to modeling](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2010/08/31/blender-intro-to-modeling/) might be a good place to start.  This site is more geared towards specific problems/questions rather than tutorial requests, so once you have some more specific questions feel free to post them here.  We hope to see you around!

Comment: PGMath ... I thought you said "Welcome to the site moron"